# Updating column based on three tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I know it's very unprofessional, but it's our business system so I can't change it.

I have three tables: `t_posList`, `t_url`, `t_type`. The table `t_posList` has a column named `URL` which is also stored in the table `t_url` (the ID of the table `t_url` is not saved in `t_posList` so I have to find it like `posList.Url = t_url.Url`).

The column `t_posList.status` of every data row should be updated to 'non-customer' (it will be a status id but lets keep it simple) if: the ID of `t_url` can NOT be found in `t_type.url_id`.

So the query has like two steps: first I have to get all of the data rows where `t_posList.Url = t_url.Url`. After this I have to check which ID's of the found `t_url` rows can **NOT** be found in `t_type.url_id`.

I really hope you know what I mean. Because our system is very unprofessional and my SQL knowledge is not that good I'm not able to make this query.

EDIT: I tried this:

```
UPDATE t_poslist SET status = ( 
    SELECT 'non-customer'
    FROM t_url, t_type
    WHERE url in 
           (select url from t_url 
            LEFT JOIN t_type ON t_url.ID = t_type.url_id 
            WHERE t_type.url_id is null)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
UPDATE p
SET status = 'non-customer'
FROM t_poslist  p
INNER JOIN t_url u ON u.url = p.url
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT * FROM t_type t WHERE t.url_id = u.ID
)
```

Comment: sory didnt work for me, but i think its a problem in my Db. I will leave it like it was, cause its a school/company project and i have to finish it until 16.04 => not on top of my prioritylist.